# If statement failing to activate

Tags: c++, arrays, function, c++11, char

I'm trying to create a function that is supposed to do the following:

-Take in two character arrays, one smaller than the other and determine whether the smaller character array is a subset of the larger array. As an example:
Array A: `{"s","c","h","o","o","l"}` ; Array B: `{"c","h"}`. I'm obligated to use pointer increment/decrement operations. This is the code that I've produced:

```
int locator(char *Bigptr, char *Smallptr) {
int count = 0;
    for (; *Bigptr != '\0'; Bigptr++) {
        if (*Smallptr == *Bigptr) {
            for (; (*Smallptr == *Bigptr) != '\0'; Smallptr++, Bigptr++) {}
            if (*Smallptr == '\0') {
                return count;
            }
            else {
                cout << "small is not the subset of big" << endl;
                return 0;
            }
        }
        count++;
    }
return 0;
```

This is how I perceive the code should run:

Two pointers to a character array are taken as parameters to the function 'locator'. The variable count is one I've placed in order to tell me what the subscript of the first character in the occurrence in A is (e.g. "school" and "ch" would be element 1 so A[1]). The first for loop ensures that the first value of the larger array is an actual character. The if statement returns true when it founds a character in common. The second for loop then checks to see if all of the smaller array is present in the larger array. When my program compiles, all of this works as expected. The problem appears with the nested if statement. I expected it to be true if, in fact, the smaller array is a subset of the larger one. Why isn't that the case? Take the example of "school" and "ch". the *Smallptr initially points to the first element of Array B (i.e. "ch"), so "c". it then is compared to "c" in "school". The two pointers are then incremented so that they both point to "h" in their respective arrays. Again, they are incremented again so that *Bigptr points to "o" and *Smallptr points to '\0'. Is that not the case? Why does the function always output the else statement?

Comment: Your arguments are arrays of character arrays, not char arrays. You need to provide a complete example.

Comment: It hit return count, where count == 1, when I ran it. I probably screwed up by passing it the right data type. Your declaration of A and B sound wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding of the second `for` loop is incorrect.

```
if (*Smallptr == *Bigptr) {
    for (; (*Smallptr == *Bigptr) != '\0'; Smallptr++, Bigptr++) {}
```

Since your have already determined (in the `if` condition that statement) that `*Smallptr == *Bigptr`, that comparison gives a non-zero (`true`) result.

The test `(*Smallptr == *Bigptr) != '\0'` compares that non-zero result with a `char` that has value zero.   Non-zero values never compare equal to zero (at least, not with standard integral types, including `bool`) so the loop has no effect.

A loop consistent with your description is

```
for (; (*Smallptr == *Bigptr) && *SmallPtr != '\0'; Smallptr++, Bigptr++) {}
```

which checks if the two characters are equal to each other, and both non-zero.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I see your point, but I had a couple of follow ups. First, you mentioned that the loop has no effect. In what sense is that? I created a dummy variable using my original code to see if the loop was working and it did indeed 'loop'. Moreover, even after having tested your suggestions, the if statement following the for loop was still false. Why would that be the case? Shouldn't the improvements you suggested then ensure that *Smallptr is indeed 'pointing' to '\0'. Thanks again for your response, I really appreciate it.

Comment: The end condition for your `for` statement is true before it is reached.   Therefore neither the loop body (in your case, that does nothing) nor the continuation statement (in your case, `Smallptr++, Bigptr++`) are ever exercised.    As I've described it, the loop will stop if either `*SmallPtr != *BigPtr` or `*SmallPtr` is zero.   If that's not what you intend, modify to suit.

Answer (score 1):

Given that this is C++, you probably want to take advantage of the capabilities already present in the standard library. I'd do something on this order:

```
bool is_subset(std::string big, std::string small) { 

    std::sort(big.begin(), big.end());
    std::sort(small.begin(), small.end());

    std::string result;
    std::set_difference(small.begin(), small.end(),
                        big.begin(), big.end(),
                        std::back_inserter(result));
    return result.empty();
}
```

This doesn't satisfy the requirements about using pointers, but IMO it's a better way to do the job.

Answer (score -1):

You had a few things wrong.
Look at this rework:

```
int locator(char *Bigptr, char *Smallptr) {
    int count = 0;
    for (; *Bigptr != '\0'; Bigptr++) {
        if (*Smallptr == *Bigptr) {
            for (; *Smallptr == *Bigptr && *Bigptr!='\0'; Smallptr++, Bigptr++) {
                count++;
            }
            if (*Smallptr == '\0') {
                return count;
            }
            break; //this is necesary in order not to stay in the main for loop
        }
    }
    std::cout << "small is not the subset of big" << std::endl;

    return count;
}
```

**EDIT:** Testing the code in the main function and it works perfectly:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    std::cout << locator("hello","ohl"); //this prints "small is not the subset of big"
    std::cout << locator("hello","ell"); //this prints "3" (the count of matching characters)
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hey José, I don't have the ability to down vote or up vote since i'm a new member, so it wasn't me. However, I did try your code and the problem persisted. So, that might be the reason another person downvoted your comment.

Comment: You are right. I was missing a "break". Additionally i think returning count always is more interesting. So the user can always get the number of matching characters. Now the code is tested and it really does what it should do.

Answer (score -1):

The logic used in the line

```
for (; (*Smallptr == *Bigptr) != '\0'; Smallptr++, Bigptr++) {}
```

is not correct.

What you need is:

```
for (; (*Smallptr == *Bigptr) && *SmallPtr != '\0'; Smallptr++, Bigptr++)
{
   ++count;
}
```